# Avoid permissions review for a Google AppScript Webapp

Tags: web-applications, permissions, google-apps-marketplace

I deployed an appScript webapp and published it on the marketplace for my company domain.

As this webapp accesses data from the user (through the DriveApp service), is there a way to avoid the user to get prompted to review the permissions at the first execution?

[image: Screenshot]

PS: I added it as a trusted App at the domain administration level (Security > G Suite API Permissions) and granted it the Data access (Apps > Marketplace apps) but it does not change anything for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization), it is standard protocol for Google to openly inform the scopes your apps has access to. This is also standard for other products like Android and other web apps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I asked this question because I wanted to call the AppScript webapp from a URL Fetch with the token of the user in the header (without any user action so). I found a workaround by deploying the appScript as an API executable, instead of a webapp and getting the user token from a service account. This way, I can access data from the user without having him to authorize the scopes first.